# How to make all child view at vertical center of a horizontal LinearLayout which gravity is center_vertical after add views to it

Tags: android

Here is a horizontal `LinearLayout`, I set it's gravity to `center_vertical`, then add two views to the `LinearLayout`, the height of first view is bigger the other, the result is the second view align top of the first view, not at vertical center of the `LinearLayout`. 
How to make all child view at vertical center, any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
Context context = getActivity();
mPictureContainer = new LinearLayout(context);
mPictureContainer.setBackgroundColor(0xffffffff);
mPictureContainer.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
mPictureContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
int leftRightMargin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.leftRightMargin);
mPictureContainer.setPadding(leftRightMargin, 0, leftRightMargin, 0);
//...
mAddPicBtn = new ImageView(context);
mAddPicBtn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(Utils.dip2px(77f), Utils.dip2px(77f)));
mAddPicBtn.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
mAddPicBtn.setImageDrawable(StateListFactory.createStateListDrawable(R.drawable.add_prs, -1, R.drawable.add));
//...
mPictureContainer.removeAllViews();
ArrayList<String> pictures = (ArrayList<String>) data.getSerializableExtra("pictures");
int size = pictures.size();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String path = pictures.get(i);
    final View view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.status_pic_item, mPictureContainer, false);
    view.setTag(path);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);
    ImageView delPicBtn = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.delPicBtn);
    delPicBtn.setImageDrawable(StateListFactory.createStateListDrawable(R.drawable.del_prs, -1, R.drawable.del));           
    delPicBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mPictureContainer.removeView(view);
            if (mPictureContainer.getChildCount() < 4 && mAddPicBtn.getParent() != mPictureContainer) {
                mPictureContainer.addView(mAddPicBtn);
            }
        }
    });
    mPictureContainer.addView(view, i);
    ImageLoader.loadImage(imageView, "file://" + path);
}
if (mPictureContainer.getChildCount() < 4) {
    mPictureContainer.addView(mAddPicBtn);
}
```

And here is the layout `status_pic_item` :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="81dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/picture"
        android:layout_width="77dp"
        android:layout_height="77dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delPicBtn"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Can you also post your code?

Comment: why are you not using RelativeLayout for this kind of representation?

Comment: @Sharj , I have post my code and the screenshot. Sorry for replying so late.

Comment: @RobinHood , I set horizontal programmatically: `mPictureContainer.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);`

Comment: I'm not sure. But I think your views are centered vertically. It's just that the image with the X has some white space. Try checking with developer options draw view bounds.

Comment: @torque203 you are right, they are in vertical center, I was deceived by my eye. Thank you!